# Using lodash with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm currently involved witha a project using underscore 1.3.3 in and backbone 0.9.2 and I'd like to incorporate lodash to take advantage of the cloneDeep() method.  We're relatively close to major release so I'd like to try to minimize the impact on the existing code base. Is it possible to incorporate lodash so that there won't be any impact on our existing underscore calls?

Comment: Stop it. Don't do that; just add `cloneDeep` to underscore if it doesn't already exist. The source should be simple enough.

Comment: Furthermore, don't include a whole library just for one method!

Comment: Also, in case your project is already using jQuery, you can do deep cloning by passing `true` as first param to `$.extend()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to mix loDash and underscore.

I would just copy and paste the cloneDeep source for now, and then work on porting your whole project over to lodash after the major release.

Answer (score 1):

First off, lodash provides an "underscore" build that's intended to be a drop-in replacement.  Consider replacing underscore with that.

If you don't want to go that route, you can use [`_.noConflict`](http://lodash.com/docs#noConflict) to assign lodash to a different variable and retain access to `_` for underscore.

Comment: I want to upvote this for the drop-in build, but I just can't support mixing the two.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either (which is why I listed it second), but sometimes the realities of your environment might not make it easy to replace a library (huge regression testing effort) and it's not ideal to try to maintain copy/pasted code from a 3rd party library.  Pick your poison, I guess.